# 2x8 insulation in a 2x6 ceiling?

Tags: insulation

My garage has a vaulted ceiling on 2x6 joists. The main roof of the building is a bit above it and the vaulted ceiling is not covered with any sheeting. I could feasibly put 2x8 batts of insulation in the cavities and then sheetrock it up. The insulation would stick out 2" or so above the joists. Would this achieve me any better R valve? or should I just use 2x6 insulation and call it a day. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually more insulation is better if you have the space.  Your use of the garage will factor  in the cost benefit of more insulation.  Would assume the walls are already insulated or will be also.

Comment: You'll probably be ok, but you can reduce the R value of the insulation when you compress it too much. At least with fiberglass insulation. If you leave it sticking out I suppose that's fine but how are you fastening it between the joists? Is there a reason you want to use 2x8? Do you already have some and just want to save money?

Comment: I will be spending a lot of time in there as it's becoming my music room/man cave. The walls will insulated with 2x4 batts of mineral wool. The ceiling is open so thicker batts will not be compressed. The batts will just be friction fit between the joists and then sheetrock put under them. I was thinking the 2x8 insulation might up the r valve and the sound isolation over the 2x6 batts, that's why I was thinking of going that route.

Comment: With open space of ceilings, usually the only limiting factor for amount of insulation is cost. Double layers not uncommon.  Will probably want a vapour barrier on top of sheetrock, under insulation.

Comment: Back to your original question, 8" batts provide more insulation that 6" batts, assuming the 8" batts are not compressed.  So I would go with the 8" bats and just leave the insulation stick above the joists.

Comment: Note that with any type of insulation, you're going to be losing heat through the joists, unless they are insulated in some fashion along their top edge.

Comment: You lose heat through _everything_. It's just a matter of how much. Adding a bit of insulation over the top of joists only adds... a bit of insulation.

Comment: Yes, more is better than less. However, you need to maintain a gap between your insulation and the roof or else you can cause ice dams. You could install insulation baffles to promote the flow of air in the winter but that is of course an additional cost.

Answer (score 2):

Compressing insulation designed for 2x8 into a 2x6 cavity will yield a negligible R-value difference.

You can buy R-21 insulation for 2x6 cavities but if you buy R-30C then it will only be worth R-22 once compressed.

Insulation is a delicate balance of air space and fiberglass. Air is a terrible conductor of heat.

[image]

[Source](https://dcpd6wotaa0mb.cloudfront.net/mdms/dms/Residential%20Insulation/10017857/10017857-Building-Insul-Compressed-R-Value-Chart-Tech-Bulletin.pdf)